# Flow: Matching argument types with disjoint unions and $Shape

Tags: flowtype

I'd like to create a function that merges an object of type `T` with a subset of properties also found in `T`. For example, given the following definition:

```
type Animal<Type: $Subtype<string>, Props: {}> = {
  name: string,
  type: Type,
} & Props;

type Cat = Animal<'CAT', {
  fuzzy: boolean,
}>;

type Dog = Animal<'DOG', {
  adventurous: boolean,
}>;
```

I'd like to have a function that takes an animal, some sub-properties of the animal, and return another object that matches the shape of the input animal.

I tried the following:

```
function augmentAnimal<T: Cat | Dog>(
  animal: T,
  augmentation: $Shape<T>,
): T {
  return {
    ...animal,
    ...augmentation,
  };
}
```

Which gives me the following error:

```
20:   return {             ^ object literal. Could not decide which case to select
16: function augmentAnimal<T: Cat | Dog>(
                              ^ union type
```

I think the part I'm confused about is having the function be able to take any Animal type and then enforce that the `augmentation` argument is of type `$Shape<OnlyOneAnimal>` instead of $Shape`.

I can create augmentation functions for each animal individually:

```
function augmentCat<T: Cat>(
  cat: T,
  catProps: $Shape<T>,
): T {
  return {
    ...cat,
    ...catProps,
  };
}
```

I just can't seem to figure out the more generic version.

Note: Animal augmentation used only for illustrative purposes. No animals were augmented or harmed in the creation of this question.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like inheritance to me.  Would interfaces help?

```
// @flow

interface Animal {
  name: string,
  type: $Subtype<string>,
};

interface Cat extends Animal {
  type: 'CAT',
  fuzzy: boolean,
};

interface Dog extends Animal {
  type: 'DOG',
  adventurous: boolean,
};

function augmentAnimal<T: Animal>(
  animal: T,
  augmentation: $Shape<T>,
): T {
  return {
    ...animal,
    ...augmentation,
  };
}

const c: Cat = {
  type: 'CAT',
  name: 'Griffin',
  fuzzy: true
};

const d: Dog = {
  type: 'DOG',
  name: 'Echo',
  adventurous: true,
};


augmentAnimal(c, {name: 'hairless'})
augmentAnimal(c, {fuzzy: false})
augmentAnimal(c, {adventurous: false})  // Error
augmentAnimal(d, {adventurous: true})
augmentAnimal(d, {fuzzy: false})  // Error
```

Comment: That's definitely closer, but it then seems impossible to update the Animal when passed a generic Animal object. For example: 

`const e: Animal = { type: 'DOG', name: 'Echo', adventurous: true };`
`augmentAnimal(c, {adventurous: false}); // Error`

With disjoint unions you'd be able to confirm it's a 'DOG' by checking its `type`, but that doesn't seem possible with this solution.